# How to execute stored function in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, stored-functions

I want to execute this stored function, and insert data in table t
I tried to find solution, but unsuccessfully

```
CREATE TABLE t (id number
              , name varchar2(32)
              , time date);

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE t_api AS
    FUNCTION func_ins (
        p_row IN t%rowtype
    ) RETURN t.id%TYPE;
END t_api;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY t_api AS
FUNCTION func_ins (
    p_row IN t%rowtype
) RETURN t.id%TYPE 
IS
    l_id t.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO t VALUES p_row RETURNING id INTO l_id;    
    RETURN l_id;
END func_ins;
END t_api;
/


declare
p_row t%rowtype;
begin
p_row.id := 1;
p_row.name := 'name';
p_row.time := sysdate;
t_api.func_ins(p_row);
end;
/
```

I got

> PLS-00221

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the specific problem you are having?  Please show how the function is being called.

Comment: You can see now, I edited post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works perfectly ,however i wouldn't recommend this design as its not a good practice to perform a DML within a function. Rather create a procedure instead of function and retrieve the Id using the out parameter.

Anonymous block to test the function when table is empty.You assign values for %ROWTYPE variable and insert.

```
  declare 
    t_row t%rowtype;
    x t.id%type;
    begin

    t_row.id := 2;
    t_row.name := 'Test2';
    t_row.time := sysdate;

     x :=  t_api.func_ins(t_row);

     dbms_output.put_line('x '||x);

    end;
```

Output is

```
 x 2
```

Modified code with Procedure to achieve the same result is below,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE t_api AS
    FUNCTION func_ins (
        p_row IN t%rowtype
    ) RETURN t.id%TYPE;
  PROCEDURE   proc_ins (
    p_row IN t%rowtype,
    l_id out t.id%TYPE
); 
END t_api;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY t_api AS
FUNCTION func_ins (
    p_row IN t%rowtype
) RETURN t.id%TYPE 
IS
    l_id t.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO t VALUES p_row RETURNING id INTO l_id;    
    RETURN l_id;
END func_ins;
PROCEDURE proc_ins (
    p_row IN t%rowtype,
    l_id out t.id%TYPE
) 
IS

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO t VALUES p_row RETURNING id INTO l_id;    

END proc_ins;
END t_api;
/
```

Anonymous block to test the procedure,

```
declare 
t_row t%rowtype;
x t.id%type;
begin


t_row.id := 3;
t_row.name := 'Test3';
t_row.time := sysdate;

 t_api.proc_ins(t_row,x);
 dbms_output.put_line('x '||x);


end;
```

Output is

x 3

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I can't insert in table with your answer

Comment: Why not? What do you get? What does it actually do? Just saying you can't insert is completely useless.

Comment: When I execute declare 
t_row t%rowtype;
x t.id%type;
begin

select * into t_row from t;
 x :=  t_api.func_ins(t_row);
end; I got ORA-01403 NO_DATA_FOUND error

Comment: I want to insert data in table with this function. Table is empty

Comment: Modified the code now to insert when the table is empty. Here you assign values to %ROWTYPE variable and then you insert.I have tested the code.

Comment: "I want to insert data in table with this function"  Why do you insist on doing it with a function instead of a procedure?  As already pointed out by @VN'sCorner, this is an improper task for a _function_.  Functions, should just query and return a result. Think about the built-in functions to_date.  That's a good example of the type of things for a function.

Comment: Thank you @EdStevens, I'll apply that.